# How do I unpack raw binary from Asus BIOS update file?

Tags: bios, eeprom

I am attempting to repair a bricked Asus X53SV notebook (Asus K53SV board) by reflashing with [flashrom](https://www.flashrom.org/Flashrom) from a Raspberry Pi. I've got it all hooked up and `flashrom` recognizes and reads the chip. However, I cannot determine what type of file the BIOS update is that I downloaded from Asus support site. The update I'm using is `K53SVAS.315` for Aptio's Easy Flash. How can I extract the raw BIOS from this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, I've determined that the download offered by Asus is not a complete BIOS image file. It cannot be used to reflash the EEPROM directly as it does not contain all of the information required. The built in Easy Flash utility uses this file to update only a portion of the EEPROM. The only officially supported method of repairing a bricked Asus notebook is to send it back to Asus.

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to fix my bricked Asus K53E using instructions from [here](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?24576-G74SX-Bricked-Bios-after-update-SOLVED!), yours should be similar. It requires you to download the first part of the flash from the chip and hope that this part is not corrupted.

You have to first dump the bricked flash, then reconstruct the full image by merging it with update file from Asus website using a hex editor as follows:

```
Reconstructed_Image 0x0 - 0x17FFFF = Bricked_Image 0x0 - 0x17FFFF
Reconstructed_Image 0x180000 - 0x3FFFFF = Update_Image 0x0 - 0x27FFFF
```